# virtualbox: using existing virtual hard disk file for new vm

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

I had an ubuntu 18.04 VM that I created using virtual box on windows 11 host.

Due to some hardware issues my laptop needed some repair. But repair caused VM to have adapter issues and VM stopped having network.
It contains some data I want, but cloning it carries those adapter/network issues to new VM.

So now I am creating a new VM(22.04). During installation, I came across this dialog, and I see that it has an option 'Use an Existing Virtual Hard Disk File', with my previous VM vdi file listed.

I was wondering if I opt for it, would it cause those adapter/network issues too on new vm or would only copy the data to new VM without those earlier issues?

[image: VHD]

Comment: Why not creating a new virtual disk for the new VM; mounting the old disk later to retrieve your data; and then getting rid of the old one.

Comment: I use old disks in VirtualBox all the time.  They still seem to work fine.  But, nothing is guaranteed to work.  Also, I have never had it corrupt or change a disk file to the point it couldn't be used.

Comment: @fedkad, thanks for suggestion.